# The default user settings stored in NSUserSettings don't seem to load

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

So I have a settings bundle in my iPhone app and my problem is that the values for the UISwitches that have default values of "enabled" are not being read from the settings bundle the first time the app is installed on a phone.

In order for the default settings to register I need to go into the iphone settings and simply view/load the settings page for my app, so that the settings get "Set". What is going on here???

Recap: I need to go into the settings app on the iPhone and simply view/load the page for my app in order for the default values to get registered into the NSUserDefaults, but I need them to load the first time the app is installed, and not on the condition that the user must go into the settings and view the page.

This is how i'm loading my settings in the viewDidLoad method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (([[defaults objectForKey:kToggleSwitch] isEqualToString:@"Enabled"]) ? YES : NO) {
//Do Stuff
}
```

P.S. I could simply set all the switches to Disabled/False values but for my app it would be preferable having certain switches on and others off.

Comment: Unless you post sample code on how you load the settings values on app startup, there's no way to tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: just posted the sample code, sorry bout that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `- (void)registerDefaults:(NSDictionary *)dictionary` to one of the methods called at application startup. You have to register your defaults at every start.
 [NSUserDefaults Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults%3a)

Btw. there is `boolForKey:`, and `setBool:ForKey:`, no need to compare strings.

Comment: by using this method can I somehow load the plist file from my settings bundle or should I just copy the plist to my resources folder and load it from there?